# How to increase JSON perameter COUNT value for pagination in swift

Tags: json, swift, pagination, uicollectionview

from backend `count start form 0. and 0,1,2,3...... . For each count 10 product is showing`

I have taken initially count = 0 like below

```
 var currentCount: Int = 0
```

**and added count perameter in JSON like below in service call:** but here always shows only 10 products in collectionview... even if there are more products then also not showing.. why?

```
fileprivate func serviceCall(){
self.currentCount+=0

let param = ["jsonrpc": "2.0",
             "params": ["type" : type, "count": currentCount]] as [String : Any]


APIReqeustManager.sharedInstance.serviceCall(param: param, vc: self, url: getUrl(of: .productByFeature), header: header) {(responseData) in
   
       if self.currentCount > 0 {
         self.viewmoreDB?.result?.products! += ViewMoreBase(dictionary: responseData.dict as NSDictionary? ?? NSDictionary())?.result?.products ?? [ViewMoreProducts]()
        }
        else{

        self.viewmoreDB = ViewMoreBase(dictionary: responseData.dict as NSDictionary? ?? NSDictionary())

        }
        self.productsData = self.viewmoreDB?.result?.products
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

**and trying to use pagination like below** at the end of the collectionview activity indicator is showing but if there are more products then also not loading

```
 func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if scrollView == collectionView{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height) == scrollView.contentSize.height {
        serviceCall()
    }
    }
}
```

please do help

Answer (score 1):

It could be any of may issues. One of the possible things is that you do not update `currentCount` when you get the data and your statement `if self.currentCount > 0` always fails and the `else` part executes which means that data is not added but overwritten and you again have just one page of data.

If this is true you are probably missing `currentCount = self.productsData.count` or even better, you should simply make your `currentCount` as a computed property doing

```
var currentCount: Int { productsData?.count ?? 0 }
```

Since this is a guess a more appropriate answer is that you need to improve your skills when debugging. One of the widely used feature which is available in most modern IDEs is using breakpoints. In most IDEs you simply click left of the line you wish to put your breakpoint and an icon shows there. When your code executes with debugger it will stop at a breakpoint and you will be able to see all the information that is currently in the stack and you will be able to execute line by line to see what is going on. So in your case you could place a breakpoint at a first line after `serviceCall` and see which path the code takes you and why.

If using Xcode there is another feature that you can use WHILE stopped on breakpoint. You can use console on your bottom right of your IDE to print out values as chunks of code. So while stopped there you could enter "po self.currentCount" and you could see the count. More interesting would be to see things like "ViewMoreBase(dictionary: responseData.dict as NSDictionary? ?? NSDictionary())?.result?.products" to check if you get any products from the backend.

Comment: actually my count is not increasing.. bcz `self.currentCount+=0` i asked to my backend how count will increase

Comment: they said `if you send count 0 , it will give you 1-10 product , if you send  count 1 then  11-20 product like this.`

Comment: what u have said in 1st peragraph is correct.. then how do i change my code

Comment: @learn_swift I see. This is usually called `page`. So in your case you need to increase page when you get a result, right? So do `currentCount += 1` when you get a response.

Comment: @learn_swift also don't forget some locking mechanism so you don't call the BE for same new data multiple times. The method `scrollViewDidScroll` will be called many time. Have something like `var loadingInProgress: Bool = false` then in your method where you load data first check `guard loadingInProgress == false else { return }`. And then lock it by calling `loadingInProgress = true` and when you get a response unlock it by calling `self.loadingInProgress = false`.